Which flavor of Ubuntu prompts for LTS upgrades
I have a 2011 iMac which is currently running Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1. I would like to install Ubuntu for my daughter, who is not very tech savvy.  In particular, I think it would be better if the Ubuntu version prompted for the LTS upgrades, since there is no way she will use line commands.  In addition, she likes photography, though I plan to add GIMP, Darktable, and Rapid Photo Downloader to any Ubuntu flavor I install.  Thoughts?

I don't fully understand what you're asking, however the code that performs release-upgrades is the same for all Ubuntu products & flavors, ie. all run https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-upgrader .  All of Ubuntu flavors are identical in release-upgrade to Ubuntu Desktop.

As long as she is not the admin is does not matter what version you pick as she can't upgrade.  "Which flavor of Ubuntu prompts for LTS upgrades"  All versions will prompt for upgrades to the next release.  "I would like to install Ubuntu for my daughter" is she going to use the system unattended? All you need is a normal USER and not a full system. You need to be the admin on that system.

This question is similar to: How to only perform LTS upgrades?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

^So any flavour, if you customise it to do so.

I don't fully understand what you're asking, however the code that performs release-upgrades is the same for all Ubuntu products & flavors, ie. all run https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-upgrader .

I'll also provide example(s) of how this can be a problem.
Lubuntu switch from LXDE to LXQt
I'm a member of the Lubuntu flavor team, and we used the LXDE desktop until Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.  All subsequent releases of Lubuntu use the LXQt desktop, and of course we QA (Quality Assurance) tested upgrades from 18.04 (LXDE) to 18.10 (LXQt), even wrote some documentation on mitigating/resolving problems encountered in the QA, before deciding we'd NOT support that upgrade.  Lubuntu did not support upgrades from Lubuntu using LXDE to Lubuntu using LXQt except via re-install.
HOWEVER, any user of Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (using LXDE) that run the Ubuntu release upgrader could still had their system upgraded; as to the code, the 18.04 system was seen as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and upgrades were allowed to 18.10 (or 20.04; both using LXQt) thus the system upgraded (to 18.10 or 20.04), the result was a broken Lubuntu desktop (breakage was sometimes minor sometimes actually; but it was there if you looked)
Ubuntu Studio switch from Xfce to KDE Plasma
Ubuntu Studio (when they switched from Xfce to KDE Plasma) encountered the same issue; Ubuntu Studio didn't support Xfce to KDE Plasma upgrades; but they were unable to stop the base Ubuntu code from allowing users to perform the upgrade, and thus break their systems (again breakage could be minor & thus overlooked by users, but was there).
All of Ubuntu flavors are identical in release-upgrade to Ubuntu Desktop.
